# What is the difference between setting the classpath and java build path in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

What are the different ways that java programs gain access to external libraries.  There is setting a classpath, modifying the build or build path, but I've seen other ways of adding jars.

Why do some libraries have to be added to the classpath while others do not. For example I'm using JSF, WTP tools, and other extra libraries but they are not in my buildpath when I view the build path of my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java Build Path is just an Eclipse thing. It's where Eclipse finds the classes needed to compile and run the classes of the project. It's thus both th compile and the run classpath.

In the case of a webapp, the webapp runs inside a Java EE web container. The web container gives access to standard Java EE classes (javax.servlet, etc.). Moreover, all the jars in WEB-INF/classes are automatically included in the classpath of the web app. So Eclipse doesn't need you to specify them in the Java Build Path. They're included automatically.

Comment: Where is the classpath stored? Is it an environment variable in the operating system or something set in the JVM?

Comment: It's passed to the JVM using the -classpath or -cp option. Open the Debug view in Eclipse, run a program inside Eclipse, right-click on the ...javaw.exe node in the Debug view, and click "Properties" to see what command is used by Eclipse to launch the program.

Answer (score 15):

The classpath is used to find classes when *executing* a Java program.  The build path is used when Eclipse is *compiling* a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

On development time.

A build path is one where you can explicitly point to third party software / jars.

By default not all third party software are added into your classpath, hence you may have to explicitly add that to your path.

On runtime.

On the other hand when you run your applications from the command line, you would prefix the classpath by using -cp to specify the third party jars.

For example in web projects you would add it to your web-inf library when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

A classpath is simply an array of classpath entries (`IClasspathEntry`) that describe the types that are available.  The classpath is an environment variable that tells where to look for class files and it is generally set to a directory or a JAR (java archive) file.

The Java build path is reflected in the structure of a Java project element.  You can query a project for its package fragment roots (`IPackageFragmentRoot`).  The build path is the classpath that is used for building a Java project (`IJavaProject`).